# Problema al actualizar un treeview y base de datos sqlite3 con rowid

Tags: python

Necesito lograr que mi código se actualice con el rowid y no con el número de remito (tanto en la base de datos como en el treeview), no consigo realizar esta modificación. No sé como modificar el código para lograrlo.

De la manera en la que se encuentra el código, en caso que el usuario necesite modificar el remito, no podrá, y tendrá que eliminarlo y volver a agregar todos los datos, lo cual no es la idea.

Necesito que la primary key sea el rowid

El problema está en la función modificar, y no entiendo como enlazar correctamente el rowid con el treeview. Por favor necesito ayuda, la entrega es el domingo hasta las 23:59 hs.

```
from os import close
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from typing import Counter
from tkinter import messagebox

# creamos la conexión a la base de datos
sqlconexion = sqlite3.connect("bascula.db")
# creamos el cursor
sqlcursor = sqlconexion.cursor()
# creamos la base de datos (solo se crea una vez luego la dejamos comentada)
sqlcursor.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DESCARGAS(FECHA_REMITO VARCHAR(10), N_REMITO VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY, REMITENTE VARCHAR(20), FECHA_DESCARGA VARCHAR(10), CHOFER VARCHAR(50), PATENTE_TRACTOR VARCHAR(8), PATENTE_TANQUE VARCHAR(8), PRODUCTO VARCHAR(10), BRUTO_ORIGEN INTEGER, TARA_ORIGEN INTEGER, NETO_ORIGEN INTEGER)"
)
remitentes = ["Enarsa", "Petrorío", "Petrolera del Suquía", "Refipampa"]
productos = ["Fuel Oil", "Gas Oil", "Biodiesel"]
raiz = Tk()
raiz.resizable(False, False)
raiz.title("Báscula")

# ---------------------Frame 1---------------------------#
f1 = LabelFrame(text="Carga de datos de origen", font=("Arial", 12), fg="white")
f1.config(bg="grey")
f1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# ----------------------Fecha S/Rto---------------------------#
lfecharto = Label(f1, text="Fecha S. Remito:")
lfecharto.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lfecharto.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

efecharto = Entry(f1)
efecharto.config(font=("Arial", 10))
efecharto.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
# ----------------------Nº de Remito---------------------------#
lrto = Label(f1, text="Nº Remito:")
lrto.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lrto.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

erto = Entry(f1)
erto.config(font=("Arial", 10))
erto.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# ----------------------Fecha de hoy---------------------------#
lfechahoy = Label(f1, text="Fecha de hoy:")
lfechahoy.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lfechahoy.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

efechahoy = Entry(f1)
efechahoy.config(font=("Arial", 10))
efechahoy.grid(row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

# ----------------------Chofer---------------------------#
lchofer = Label(f1, text="Chofer:")
lchofer.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lchofer.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

echofer = Entry(f1)
echofer.config(font=("Arial", 10))
echofer.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# ----------------------Patente Tractor---------------------------#
lpatentet = Label(f1, text="Patente Tractor:")
lpatentet.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lpatentet.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

epatentet = Entry(f1)
epatentet.config(font=("Arial", 10))
epatentet.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Patente Tanque---------------------------#
lpatenteta = Label(f1, text="Patente Tanque:")
lpatenteta.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lpatenteta.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

epatenteta = Entry(f1)
epatenteta.config(font=("Arial", 10))
epatenteta.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Remito de:---------------------------#
lremitode = Label(f1, text="Remito de:")
lremitode.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lremitode.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

cremito = ttk.Combobox(f1, values=remitentes)
cremito.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Producto:---------------------------#
lproducto = Label(f1, text="Producto:")
lproducto.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lproducto.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

cproducto = ttk.Combobox(f1, values=productos)
cproducto.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Bruto origen---------------------------#
lbrutoo = Label(f1, text="Bruto")
lbrutoo.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lbrutoo.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

ebrutoo = Entry(f1)
ebrutoo.config(font=("Arial", 10))
ebrutoo.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Tara origen---------------------------#
ltarao = Label(f1, text="Tara")
ltarao.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
ltarao.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

etarao = Entry(f1)
etarao.config(font=("Arial", 10))
etarao.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Neto origen---------------------------#
lnetoo = Label(f1, text="Neto")
lnetoo.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 10))
lnetoo.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

enetoo = Entry(f1)
enetoo.config(font=("Arial", 10))
enetoo.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Frame 2---------------------------#
f2 = LabelFrame(raiz, text="Acciones", font=("Arial", 12), fg="white")
f2.config(bg="grey")
f2.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# ---------------------Frame 3---------------------------#
f3 = Frame(raiz)
f3.config(bg="grey")
f3.pack(expand=1)

# ---------------------Esperando a descargar---------------------------#
espera = ttk.Treeview(f3, height=8)
espera.grid(row=1, column=0)
espera["columns"] = (
    "ID",
    "Fecha S. Remito",
    "Nº Remito",
    "Remito de",
    "Fecha de Hoy",
    "Chofer",
    "Patente Tractor",
    "Patente Tanque",
    "Producto",
    "Bruto",
    "Tara",
    "Neto",
)
espera.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
espera.column("ID", anchor="center", width=35)
espera.column("Fecha S. Remito", anchor="center", width=120)
espera.column("Nº Remito", anchor="center", width=100)
espera.column("Remito de", anchor="center", width=100)
espera.column("Fecha de Hoy", anchor="center", width=100)
espera.column("Chofer", anchor="w", width=180)
espera.column("Patente Tractor", anchor="center", width=120)
espera.column("Patente Tanque", anchor="center", width=120)
espera.column("Producto", anchor="center", width=100)
espera.column("Bruto", anchor="center", width=60)
espera.column("Tara", anchor="center", width=60)
espera.column("Neto", anchor="center", width=60)

espera.heading("#0")
espera.heading("ID", text="ID")
espera.heading("Fecha S. Remito", text="Fecha S. Remito")
espera.heading("Nº Remito", text="Nº Remito")
espera.heading("Remito de", text="Remito de")
espera.heading("Fecha de Hoy", text="Fecha de Hoy")
espera.heading("Chofer", text="Chofer")
espera.heading("Patente Tractor", text="Patente Tractor")
espera.heading("Patente Tanque", text="Patente Tanque")
espera.heading("Producto", text="Producto")
espera.heading("Bruto", text="Bruto")
espera.heading("Tara", text="Tara")
espera.heading("Neto", text="Neto")

# agregar datos
datos = []
# contador
global contar
contar = 0
for agregar in datos:
    espera.insert(
        parent="",
        index="end",
        iid=contar,
        text="",
        values=(
            datos[0],
            datos[1],
            datos[2],
            datos[3],
            datos[4],
            datos[5],
            datos[6],
            datos[7],
            datos[8],
            datos[9],
            datos[10],
        ),
    )
    contar += 1

# función agregar datos de origen
def agregar_origen():
    global contar
    espera.insert(
        parent="",
        index="end",
        iid=contar,
        text="",
        values=(
            "",
            efecharto.get(),
            erto.get(),
            cremito.get(),
            efechahoy.get(),
            echofer.get(),
            epatentet.get(),
            epatenteta.get(),
            cproducto.get(),
            ebrutoo.get(),
            etarao.get(),
            enetoo.get(),
        ),
    )
    contar += 1


# ---------------------Función consulta---------------------------#
def consulta():
    for i in espera.get_children():
        espera.delete(i)
    # Creamos la conexión a la base de datos
    sqlconexion = sqlite3.connect("bascula.db")
    # creamos el cursor
    sqlcursor = sqlconexion.cursor()
    # Consultar la base de datos
    sqlcursor.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM DESCARGAS")
    guardados = sqlcursor.fetchall()
    # agregar los guardados en el treeview espera
    global contar
    contar = 0
    for datos in guardados:
        espera.insert(
            parent="",
            index=contar,
            text="",
            values=(
                datos[0],
                datos[1],
                datos[2],
                datos[3],
                datos[4],
                datos[5],
                datos[6],
                datos[7],
                datos[8],
                datos[9],
                datos[10],
                datos[11],
            ),
        )
    contar += 1

    sqlconexion.commit()
    # cerrar conexión a la base de datos
    sqlconexion.close()


def chequear():
    if len(erto.get()) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Atención", "Debe ingresar el número de remito")


# ---------------------Guardamos en la base de datos---------------------------#
def guardarorigen():
    if (
        len(erto.get())
        and len(efecharto.get())
        and len(cremito.get())
        and len(efechahoy.get())
        and len(echofer.get())
        and len(epatentet.get())
        and len(epatenteta.get())
        and len(cproducto.get())
        and len(etarao.get())
        and len(enetoo.get())
        and len(efecharto.get())
    ) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Atención", "Debe completar todos los datos")
    else:
        agregar_origen()
        # Creamos la conexión a la base de datos
        sqlconexion = sqlite3.connect("bascula.db")
        # creamos el cursor
        sqlcursor = sqlconexion.cursor()
        # Insertamos en la tabla
        sqlconexion.execute(
            "INSERT INTO DESCARGAS VALUES (:efecharto ,:erto ,:cremito ,:efechahoy ,:echofer ,:epatentet ,:epatenteta , :cproducto ,:ebrutoo ,:etarao ,:enetoo)",
            {
                "efecharto": efecharto.get(),
                "erto": erto.get(),
                "cremito": cremito.get(),
                "efechahoy": efechahoy.get(),
                "echofer": echofer.get(),
                "epatentet": epatentet.get(),
                "epatenteta": epatenteta.get(),
                "cproducto": cproducto.get(),
                "ebrutoo": ebrutoo.get(),
                "etarao": etarao.get(),
                "enetoo": enetoo.get(),
            },
        )

        # limpiar las entry
        efecharto.delete(0, END)
        erto.delete(0, END)
        efechahoy.delete(0, END)
        echofer.delete(0, END)
        epatentet.delete(0, END)
        epatenteta.delete(0, END)
        cremito.delete(0, END)
        cproducto.delete(0, END)
        ebrutoo.delete(0, END)
        etarao.delete(0, END)
        enetoo.delete(0, END)

        sqlconexion.commit()
        # cerrar conexión a la base de datos
        sqlconexion.close()
        # ---------------------Rellenar automáticamente el treeview sin apretar el botón---------------------------#
        consulta()

        messagebox.showinfo(message="Sus datos fueron guardados", title="Atención")


# ---------------------Funcion modificar registro---------------------------#
def modificar():
    # tomamos el número de elegido
    elegido = espera.focus()
    # actualizamos el elegido en el treeview
    espera.item(
        elegido,
        text="",
        values=(
            "",
            efecharto.get(),
            erto.get(),
            cremito.get(),
            efechahoy.get(),
            echofer.get(),
            epatentet.get(),
            epatenteta.get(),
            cproducto.get(),
            ebrutoo.get(),
            etarao.get(),
            enetoo.get(),
        ),
    )
    # ---------Actualizamos la base de datos-----#
    # Creamos la conexión a la base de datos
    sqlconexion = sqlite3.connect("bascula.db")
    # creamos el cursor
    sqlcursor = sqlconexion.cursor()

    sqlcursor.execute(
        """UPDATE DESCARGAS SET
        
        FECHA_REMITO = :fecharto,
        N_REMITO = :rto,
        REMITENTE = :remito,
        FECHA_DESCARGA = :fechahoy,
        CHOFER = :chofer,
        PATENTE_TRACTOR = :patentet,
        PATENTE_TANQUE = :patenteta,
        PRODUCTO = :producto,
        BRUTO_ORIGEN = :brutoo,
        TARA_ORIGEN = :tarao,
        NETO_ORIGEN = :netoo

        WHERE N_REMITO = :rto""",
        {
            "fecharto": efecharto.get(),
            "rto": erto.get(),
            "remito": cremito.get(),
            "fechahoy": efechahoy.get(),
            "chofer": echofer.get(),
            "patentet": epatentet.get(),
            "patenteta": epatenteta.get(),
            "producto": cproducto.get(),
            "brutoo": ebrutoo.get(),
            "tarao": etarao.get(),
            "netoo": enetoo.get(),
        },
    )

    sqlconexion.commit()
    # cerrar conexión a la base de datos
    sqlconexion.close()
    consulta()

    # limpiar las entry
    efecharto.delete(0, END)
    erto.delete(0, END)
    efechahoy.delete(0, END)
    echofer.delete(0, END)
    epatentet.delete(0, END)
    epatenteta.delete(0, END)
    cremito.delete(0, END)
    cproducto.delete(0, END)
    ebrutoo.delete(0, END)
    etarao.delete(0, END)
    enetoo.delete(0, END)


# ---------------------Funcion eliminar todos---------------------------#
def eliminar_todos():
    for agregar in espera.get_children():
        espera.delete(agregar)


# ---------------------Funcion eliminar seleccionado---------------------------#
def eliminar_seleccionado():
    x = espera.selection()[0]
    espera.delete(x)
    sqlconexion = sqlite3.connect("bascula.db")
    # creamos el cursor
    sqlcursor = sqlconexion.cursor()

    # eliminar de la base de datos
    sqlcursor.execute("DELETE from DESCARGAS WHERE N_REMITO=" + erto.get())

    sqlconexion.commit()
    # cerrar conexión a la base de datos
    sqlconexion.close()
    consulta()
    # limpiar las entry
    efecharto.delete(0, END)
    erto.delete(0, END)
    efechahoy.delete(0, END)
    echofer.delete(0, END)
    epatentet.delete(0, END)
    epatenteta.delete(0, END)
    cremito.delete(0, END)
    cproducto.delete(0, END)
    ebrutoo.delete(0, END)
    etarao.delete(0, END)
    enetoo.delete(0, END)
    messagebox.showinfo("Eliminado", "Su registro ha sido eliminado")


# ---------------------Botón Guardar origen---------------------------#

guorigen = Button(f2, text="Guardar datos de origen", command=guardarorigen)
guorigen.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Modificar registro---------------------------#

guorigen = Button(f2, text="Modificar", command=modificar)
guorigen.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Limpiar las entradas singular---------------------------#
def limpiar():
    # limpiar las entry
    efecharto.delete(0, END)
    erto.delete(0, END)
    efechahoy.delete(0, END)
    echofer.delete(0, END)
    epatentet.delete(0, END)
    epatenteta.delete(0, END)
    cremito.delete(0, END)
    cproducto.delete(0, END)
    ebrutoo.delete(0, END)
    etarao.delete(0, END)
    enetoo.delete(0, END)


# ---------------------Elegir registro singular---------------------------#
def elegir(e):
    # limpiar las entry
    efecharto.delete(0, END)
    erto.delete(0, END)
    efechahoy.delete(0, END)
    echofer.delete(0, END)
    epatentet.delete(0, END)
    epatenteta.delete(0, END)
    cremito.delete(0, END)
    cproducto.delete(0, END)
    ebrutoo.delete(0, END)
    etarao.delete(0, END)
    enetoo.delete(0, END)

    # tomamos el número de elegido
    elegido = espera.focus()
    # tomamos los valores del elegido
    valores = espera.item(elegido, "values")

    # relleno a las entry
    efecharto.insert(0, valores[1])
    erto.insert(0, valores[2])
    cremito.insert(0, valores[3])
    efechahoy.insert(0, valores[4])
    echofer.insert(0, valores[5])
    epatentet.insert(0, valores[6])
    epatenteta.insert(0, valores[7])
    cproducto.insert(0, valores[8])
    ebrutoo.insert(0, valores[9])
    etarao.insert(0, valores[10])
    enetoo.insert(0, valores[11])


# ---------------------Limpiar entradas seleccionado---------------------------#

moorigen = Button(f2, text="Limpiar entradas", command=limpiar)
moorigen.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Rellenar automáticamente el treeview sin apretar el botón---------------------------#
# bind
espera.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", elegir)

# ---------------------Botón traer listado de la base de datos---------------------------#
consultao = Button(f2, text="Traer listado", command=consulta)
consultao.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Eliminar seleccionado---------------------------#
elorigensel = Button(f2, text="Eliminar seleccionado", command=eliminar_seleccionado)
elorigensel.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Botón eliminar todos---------------------------#

elorigen = Button(f2, text="Eliminar todos del Treeview", command=eliminar_todos)
elorigen.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=10, pady=10)

# ---------------------Esperando a ser ingresado---------------------------#
lpatentet = Label(f3, text="Esperando para ingresar a descargar")
lpatentet.config(bg="grey", fg="white", font=("Arial", 12))
lpatentet.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=3)


# realizar cambios en la base de datos
sqlconexion.commit()
# cerrar conexión a la base de datos
sqlconexion.close()
# cerrar loop infinito tkinter
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probaste con crear una columna que contenga el rowid de cada registro y eliminar la columna cuyo rowid coincida con el rowid del item seleccionado?

Comment: no supe hacerlo, la verdad estoy perdido